# Oracle sql developer : can we execute for exchange command in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I am executing below command in oracle sql developer version 20.4

> create table tmp for exchange with table src;

But facing issue `missing or invalid option`

Not sure if we can run exchange for command in oracle sql developer.

Can someone help or provide any insight if the syntax is wrong or is it possible to run this command

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks fine, assuming that's a partitioned table, on 12.2 or higher of the database.

[Docs here.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/maintenance-partition-tables-indexes.html#GUID-2DE24EE4-00EB-4D58-A428-8E6CBD7E7F34)

You don't mention your version of Oracle Database - that's very important as this is a *relatively* new feature.

[Tim AKA Oracle-Base has a complete demo here.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/create-table-for-exchange-with-table-12cr2)

Reproducing Tim's example on a 19c db (think of that as 12.2.X, the last update for the 12c product line) -

```
drop table t1 purge;

create table t1 (
  id            number,
  code          varchar2(10),
  description   varchar2(50),
  created_date  date,
  data_1        varchar2(1000),
  data_2        varchar2(1000),
  constraint t1_pk primary key (id)
)
partition by range (created_date)
(
  partition t1_2017 values less than (date '2018-01-01'),
  partition t1_2018 values less than (date '2019-01-01')
);

create table t1_temp 
  /* tablespace users */
  for exchange with table t1;
```

Last command as run in SQL Dev -

[image]

Comment: Its oracle sql developer 20.4

Comment: I tried with tablespace as well but it was not working

Comment: you're ignoring the part where I asked about your version of Oracle Database - the version of SQL Developer makes exactly ZERO difference here. BTW, 20.4 is 1.5 years old already, 22.2 will be out today/tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is 12c enterprise edition 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: So with 12.1 it is not possible, right ?

Comment: It appears not - the docs/articles shard all clearly state 12.2 vs 12.1

Comment: Can we do the same in 12.1 which is doing by for exchange in 12.2

Comment: Create table by select is not doing the needful

Comment: upgrading off of 12.1 to 19c should be pretty high on your to-do list. 12.1 platform is no longer being supported.

Comment: Wish i could .  As there is like no or little chance. I did it via create table but then i have to disable the constraint, which could lead to data corrupt